# How can I keep datalist showing items in the drop down menu?

Tags: html, html-datalist

If I use the normal datalist, for example, like this.

```
<input name="example" list="example" />
<datalist id="example">
    <option value="Value1"></option>
    <option value="Value2"></option>
</datalist>
```

When I click on an item, it starts only showing that element. And I can't go back to see all the items. How can I fix that?

Note that I don't want to use `select` either, because it doesn't allow me to copy an entry.

Answer (score 1):

That is one of Datalist's limitations, but there are some workarounds: http://pebbleroad.github.io/combo-select/